# Exception when trying to use Google Calendar API in android

Tags: android, authorization, google-calendar-api

I am getting exception as below:
[image: Access not configured]

Well, I've used or say copied same code as this shown in google doc https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android .And I know it is the same error which is already mentioned in troubleshooting part of this doc but as mentioned in its solution, I had checked my SHA1 fingerprint and also package name and all the stuffs but still getting same error. And also I tried to google and followed each and every link the google suggested but nothing works for me so my last option was STACKOVERFLOW and so I am here. Please help if any one can. Thanks in advance.

Also I forgot to mention, it says "Unregistered Android application" it means that the OAuth2 client ID I created is not found by the app but I don't know how can I make it find my OAuth2 client ID and solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that:-

- You enabled calendar API in google console for that project you are using, as the link provide in your response.
- Also match your package name in AndroidManifest is similar to the package you mentioned in google dev console with SHA.

Comment: Thanks @Vindhya Pratap Singh , I already did both the things you mentioned in your answer, but still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an [Oauth client id](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) under corresponding project in google console. Follow the steps in this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en).

> To create an OAuth 2.0 client ID in the console:
>
> 1. Go to the [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
> 2. From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
> 3. If the API Manager page isn't already open, open the console menu and select **API Manager**.
> 4. On the left, click **Credentials**.
> 5. Click **New Credentials**, then select **OAuth client ID**.
>
> ***Note***: If you're unsure whether OAuth 2.0 is appropriate for your project, select **Help me choose** and follow the instructions to pick
>   the right credentials.
>
> 6. Select the appropriate application type for your project and enter any additional information required. Application types are described
>      in more detail in the following sections.
> 7. If this is your first time creating a client ID, you can also configure your consent screen by clicking **Consent Screen**. (The
>      [following
>      procedure](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#userconsent)
>      explains how to set up the Consent screen.) You won't be prompted to
>      configure the consent screen after you do it the first time.
> 8. Click **Create client ID**.

Based also from this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863022/edit-google-calendar-events-from-google-service-account-403/11897793#11897793), you have to give permission from your calendar configuration *(Calendar configuration -> Share this calendar)* to the email account specified into Google Api Console (email adress).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry to say but I followed all your above steps but it doesn't help. :(